# Codeigniter ajax email form

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, contact-form

I'm implementing an ajax contact form in Codeigniter. Can't seem to figure out what my issue is. When running the script through Firebug, there is a POST error in jquery.min.js which doesn't seem to make much sense. Maybe there's a syntax error I'm missing?

Here is my ajax JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Ajax contact form
    $('#submit').click(function() {

        var form_data = {
            first_name : $('.first_name').val(),
            last_name : $('.last_name').val(),
            email : $('.email').val(),
            message : $('.message').val(),
            ajax : '1'
        };
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : "http://localhost/web/hfs/home/contact",
            async : false,
            data : form_data,

            success : function(msg) {
                $('#left-container.thankyou').html(msg);

            }
        });
        // end ajax
        return false;
    });
});
```

And here is my controller function:

```
public function contact() {
    if ($this -> input -> post('ajax') == '1') {
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required|min_length[1]');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required|min_length[1]');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('message', 'Message', 'required|min_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Please fill in the fields');

        if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE) {
            echo validation_errors();
        } else {
            echo "Thanks for contacting!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at it in Chrome, open the developer console (F12) before clicking the send button. Go to Network then in the bottom right click XHR. You'll see each request, if it failed it will be red, then you can click on each one and see what data was sent, where it was sent and the responses. That should help you track down the error.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Listen for the submit event on the form and use `data : $(this).serialize()`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="myform">
        <input type="text" name="a" value="Some value in A" id="a" />
        <input type="text" name="b" value="Some value in B" id="b" /></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <p id="thankyou"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myform").submit(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : "http://localhost/web/hfs/home/contact",
                    async : false,
                    data : $(this).serialize(),
                    success : function(msg) {
                        $('#thankyou').html(msg);

                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```